# How do you configure mvc-mini-profiler with EF 4.2 Code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, c#-4.0, mvc-mini-profiler

EF 4.1 Update 1 had an error in it with regards to profiling that has now been fixed and I am trying to get profiling working using MySql with EF 4.2 Code First.

I tried putting

MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();

in my application start but received the error

Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Comment: Just as a note If you take the code as is that is checked into the MiniProfiler project on Github the above code works fine so not sure what error there is as it has been fixed and not pushed to NuGet

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/mvc-mini-profiler/

> **EF 4.1 Update 1**
>
> Note, that EF 4.1 Update 1 (version currently on NuGet) has a breaking
>   change which throws the following error when specifying a connection
>   string:
>
> `The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131047)`
>
> MiniProfiler attempts to resolve this issue by detecting the version
>   of EntityFramework that it is running against. If this doesn't work
>   (due to security exceptions), force the hack to be applied by
>   replacing the Initialize() call with:
>
> `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize_EF42(); // in Application_Start`
>
> However, this is currently unable to profile SqlCE or Oracle
>   databases.
>
> To work around this an additional parameter has been added to the
>   Initialize call:
>
> If you specify connection strings explicitly in your web.config, use
>   `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize();`. This will not profile SqlCE or Oracle
>   databases If you don't specify connection strings (automatically
>   inferred) and want SqlCE support, use
>   `MiniProfilerEF.Initialize(false);`. Note, this should be a temporary
>   solution until EF 4.2 is widely available.